# What are some interesting uses for Java Agents?

Tags: java, classloader, javaagents

Starting with Java 5 there's an option to add Java Agents to the class loader.

Have you written any Agents?
have you used any Agents?
What are interesting uses of Agents?

Answer (score 2):

I have used various java profilers that use this feature. A good open source java profiler that uses this is Profiler4j (http://profiler4j.sourceforge.net).

This is a great tool for finding performance bottlnecks in your java code.